# How to prevent Bower from bloating my app?

Tags: yeoman, bower

I'm working on a little web application using Express.js, Backbone.js, Bootstrap and some others. I've decided to give Bower a try to manage the front end components for this one, but after installing the packages, I noticed that all of them installed tons of stuff that I don't need at all, like LESS files (Bootstrap) or QUnit tests for the framework (Backbone), README.md files, documentation source code, and so on:

[image: Bower Madness]

As you can see, it's absolute madness in here.

I've searched the package index a bit and I've found a leaner version of Bootstrap called bootstrap.css, but after installing I noticed it is still version 2.3.2, so pretty much outdated.

Isn't there a way to install up to date **dist** versions of all those libraries?

The idea of having a package manager is nice but it seems a bit off putting to have my application source bloated with all this stuff. I most definitely do not need the Backbone documentation installed on my web server.

Answer (score 4):

This is a matter of package authors not configuring their `bower.json` to ignore those extraneous files and folders. Additionally, not all package authors configure their `bower.json` to list the main file(s) for their package.

You can see how without having those two pieces of information-- what files aren't needed, and which ones are the "main" files-- Bower, or any other tool, can't reliably guess what is necessary and what is junk.

As far as it bloating your server; ideally, you shouldn't be committing Bower components. You would have a build process that takes your source files, wherever they may be on disk, and morphs them into one minified file.

Comment: Bower docs mentions a [post](http://addyosmani.com/blog/checking-in-front-end-dependencies/) by Addy Osmani that contradicts your last sentence. If it's not a packaget meant to be consumed by others, you should commit your components into your VCS.

Comment: Just like every decision in software, there are multiple ways to solve a problem, and one that's right for your app might not be right for my app. If your app uses common packages, jQuery, angular, backbone, etc., I wouldn't fear them misusing semver any time soon. And, your app is probably not that frequently visited that you couldn't catch any version discrepancies locally before a visitor saw one in production. Don't forget, as well, you're serving minified vendor files in production. My advice in my answer above says your build process should take source and make them small and ugly.

Comment: That's the file that goes to your prod server, thus you know it works, since, as long as you trust your minifier, you were just seeing it all work before you ran the build. Overall, my personal stance is: if your app is mission critical, check in your deps. If not, don't worry about it. P.S. My name is on the post you linked. Unless it's been edited dramatically since when it was posted, no specific "do this" advice was given. It's just a collection of preferences.

Comment: Stephen, the post indeed does not provide a "do this" advice, but the bower docs that point to that post do, so I just thought it would be best to add a comment about it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [bowercopy](https://github.com/timmywil/grunt-bowercopy).
What does it do?

1. Download all the bower components listed in bower.json
2. Copy files you need to specified folder
3. (Optional) Remove the bower_components folder.

Every time you run the bowercopy task, it will do the process above.

A grunt config example

```
    bowercopy: {
        options: {
            destPrefix:'app/jslib',  // Here is the dest folder 
            clean:true // It's optinal
        },
        dist: {
           // List all the files you need here
           src:'backbone/backbone.js' // "src" can be an array
        }
    }
```

Yeah, You have to specify all the files you need one by one. But it does achieve your goal.